# Drop primary key and add in Transact-SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I've researched and tried everything, I don't know if I'm missing something but here is my attempt at a dropping the primary key

```
Alter Table Course
Drop constraint PK_Course_CourseID
Go
```

Table name is `Course` and the PK is `CourseID`. I then need to re-add the PK constraint to column "row"

Comment: Is the PK an Identity Column?  Edit your question to show the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a primary key constraint:

In Object Explorer, right-click the table with the primary key, and click Design.

The table opens in Table Designer.

In the table grid, right-click the row with the primary key and choose Remove Primary Key to toggle the setting from on to off.

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190621(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: That doesn't work across the entire program I dont think. I added the PK do a different column and added it as " IS IDENTITY" so it auto increments and when I tried to add another record using the previous PK it still crashed saying PK error, I've always been told it is not a good idea to ever alter a table in the explorer because it doesnt alter it in every spot in the program

Comment: What does the exact error say? I just tried this, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Drop primary key:

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(512), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);    
SELECT @table = N'dbo.Course';

SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table 
    + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name + ';'
    FROM sys.key_constraints
    WHERE [type] = 'PK'
    AND [parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table);

EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;
```

Change previous column type (if was seed/auto-increment):

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Course
   ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName INT
```

Add PK

```
ALTER TABLE Course ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @V_CONSTRAINTNAME NVARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @V_QUERY NVARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
SELECT @V_CONSTRAINTNAME = constraint_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_constraints 
WHERE table_name = 'Course'
AND constraint_type ='PRIMARY KEY';
IF @V_CONSTRAINTNAME IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
SET @V_QUERY = 'ALTER TABLE #DBNAME#.#USERNAME#.Course DROP CONSTRAINT '+ @V_CONSTRAINTNAME;
exec sp_executesql @V_QUERY;
END;
END
GO

DECLARE @V_COUNT INT;
BEGIN
SET @V_COUNT = 0;
SELECT @V_COUNT = COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_constraints WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Course' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY';
IF @V_COUNT = 0
BEGIN
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'ALTER TABLE #DBNAME#.#USERNAME#.Course ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Course_CourseID PRIMARY KEY (row)';
END;
END;
GO